# Some db with pics in svn

Tags: database, svn, version-control

I have a large set of picture, which I plan to save in some ODB. Thse pictures can be changed after insertion into the database (although not often).

My question: How can I use SVN in connection with these pictures?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite. It's light and easy to use RDBMS engine. The whole database is just one file, so you can commit to SVN and have all revisions there.

Comment: Can I save my pics and picnames in SQLite? (there are *.png's and text's (nameparts with specified convention)). I thought I must take some objectdb to achieve an aim?

Comment: You can use SQLite, and objectdb. I have worked with SQLite, it's pretty easy and support is available in lots of platforms including Mobile.